# In a Vue component, how to update this.key data property in a loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, vue.js

In a Vue Js component, I need to loop through an object on the mounted hook that's in local storage in Vuex to update the data properties as you can see in code example.

I'm trying to update `this.title`, `this.body`, `this.id` whereby the `rightHere` variable in the loop is outputting these names as string values as the `var` you can see.

```
this.rightHere
```

...is the problem I know, and is obviously trying to target a data property "rightHere" which doesn't exist.  But I don't know how else to overcome this in javascript and make rightHere output the string as needed? So how do I use this in a loop to dynamically change but tell Vue to update `this.` on each iteration?

```
data() {
    return {
        title: '',
        body: '',
        id: '',
    }
},

mounted() {
    for (var rightHere in this.$store.getters.getObject) {
        if (this.$store.getters.getObject.hasOwnProperty(rightHere )) {
            this.rightHere = this.$store.getters.getObject[rightHere ]
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: this might be helpful https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: where do you declare this key?

Comment: Are you trying to update the [list rendering key](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key)? Why?

Comment: I'm trying to update `this.title`, `this.body`, `this.id` whereby the `key` is outputting these names as string values.

Comment: It's not quite clear from your question, but are you maybe looking for `this[key] = this.$store.getters.getObject[key]`?   (I wouldn't do that, though, I'd enumerate the fields I actually wanted to transfer instead of blindly copying all of them: `this.id = this.$store.getters.getObject.id` for example)

Comment: (Your use of the variable name "key" is causing some confusion here because that name has a particular use in Vue v-for loops, which -- unless I'm completely misunderstanding you -- doesn't appear to be what you're asking about.)

Comment: I've updated question now to avoid the use of key as my variable to help clear this up.  I'm sure it's just simple JS syntax output that's required - I just don't know what it is... :(

Comment: `this[key] = ` is working as needed actually, so simple as I thought.  Thanks @daniel-beck . However, as you say, you wouldn't do this?  What's your advice as I'm not sure how to "enumerate the fields"?

Comment: No problem! I just meant it’d be safer to check for those three specific key names and copy them over, instead of iterating through every property that might be in the store — you might not want them all attached to the vue component.

Comment: Got ya. Makes sense!  I'll accept your answer if you leave it.  Cheers

Comment: @Jquestions A better approach might be to use [`mapGetters`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html)

Answer (score 0):

You would typically set the key in your template.  It's a reserved word.

```
<div v-for='item in items' :key='$store.getters.getKey(item)'>{{item.title}}</div>
```